# IPSec/L2TP Unable to connect

Tags: macos, vpn, authorization

When attempting to connect to my StrongSwan server I'm getting getting an error message saying the server did not respond.  However, looking in /var/log/system.log shows that it is responding but that the system isn't able to open /etc/authorization.

My understanding, as a Mac noob, is that /etc/authorization is deprecated in Mavericks which is what I'm running here.

Also, the connection is set up through the native Mac networking tool, the certs are loaded in Keychain Access, and I'm using IKEv1.

Unfortunately as I noted, I'm a Mac noob and not sure where to start my search on correcting this error.  What I've found so far are just posts about how Mavericks has deprecated /etc/authorization, but not what to do if for some reason an application is attempting to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching I found the answer at http://www.henrywang.org/entry/mavericks-and-cisco-vpn (Warning : Written in Chinese you'll probably need to translate it.).

TL;DR The private key needed to be set to "Allow all applications to access this item" in  Keychain Access.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they exist, but you could try using a third-party VPN client.

**Update:** [Viscocity from SparkLabs](https://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity/) looks like it would do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately Viscosity is for OpenVPN only.  Really trying to get this working through the default Mac network configuration if I can though.